# Best way to handle large amount of nested data in powershell?

Tags: powershell, nested, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to automate the logfiles verification of our daily batch.

I want to check around 20 servers that may have up to 30 batch, each batch can generate one or more logfiles and I want to validate them using several criteria.
So this ends up with a quite huge amount of data.

My first though was to use nested arrays and hashtables then create psobject like this :

```
$servers=@(
    @{
     "name"="server1";
     "credential"="domain\user";
     "batch"=@(
                @{"batchName"="test";"path"="e:\cit\sauvegarde\batch\recup.cmd";"comment"="batch de test";"schedule"="lundi,mardi ";
                    "validations"=@(
                        @{"name"="log exist";"path"="\\smacweb\e$\cit\test.log";"filter"=@("NotNull";"NotOlderThan,2") };
                        @{"name"="no erros";"path"="\\smacweb\CIT\sauvegarde\logs\*.log";"filter"=@("NotContains,'error'") };
                )};
                @{"batchName"="mysql";"comment"="dump des bases mysql";"schedule"="lundi,mardi,vendredi";
                    "validations"=@(
                        @{"name"="log exist";"path"="\\smacweb\e$\mysqldump\dump.zip";"filter"=@("NotNull";"NotOlderThan,2") };
                        @{"name"="zipOK";"path"="\\smacweb\e$\mysqldump\dump.zip";"filter"=@("Test-Zip") };
                )};
       )
    };
#     @{
#     "name"="server2";
#     "credential"="domain\user2";
#     "batch"=@(
#                @{"batchName"=.....};
#     )};
)

$srv=@()
$servers | % {
        $srv+= New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $_;
}
```

This is a small example but I guess it will quickly become hardly readable.
So what would be a better way to do this? Use xml (not familiar to me), use external database, other method?

Comment: XML is propably the smartest choice. At least to split the validation-rules from the PS-script. I'm not familiar enough with xml to provide an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution: I'm a noob when it comes to xml, but I gave it a try for fun. This is just an example of how you could navigate through the xml-file. :)

XML file (test.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<servers>
  <server>
    <servername>server1</servername>
    <credential>domain\user</credential>
    <batches>
      <batch>
        <batchname>test</batchname>
        <batchpath>e:\cit\sauvegarde\batch\recup.cmd</batchpath>
        <comment>batch de test</comment>
        <schedule>
          <day>lundi</day>
          <day>mardi</day>
        </schedule>
        <validations>
          <validation>
            <name>log exist</name>
            <path>\\smacweb\e$\cit\test.log</path>
            <filters>
              <filter>NotNull</filter>
              <filter>NotOlderThan,2</filter>
            </filters>
          </validation>
          <validation>
            <name>no erros</name>
            <path>\\smacweb\CIT\sauvegarde\logs\*.log</path>
            <filters>
              <filter>NotContains,'error'</filter>
            </filters>
          </validation>
        </validations>
      </batch>
      <batch>
        <batchname>mysql</batchname>
        <comment>dump des bases mysql</comment>
        <schedule>
          <day>lundi</day>
          <day>mardi</day>
          <day>vendredi</day>
        </schedule>
        <validations>
          <validation>
            <name>log exist</name>
            <path>\\smacweb\e$\mysqldump\dump.zip</path>
            <filters>
              <filter>NotNull</filter>
              <filter>NotOlderThan,2</filter>
            </filters>
          </validation>
          <validation>
            <name>zipOK</name>
            <path>\\smacweb\e$\mysqldump\dump.zip</path>
            <filters>
              <filter>Test-Zip</filter>
            </filters>
          </validation>
        </validations>
      </batch>
    </batches>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Powershell-script to loop through servers and batches:

```
function test {
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\test.xml)

    $servers = $xml.SelectNodes("/servers/server")

    foreach ($server in $servers) {
        $batches = $server.SelectNodes("batches/batch")

        Write-Host "Server: $($server.servername)"
        foreach ($batch in $batches) {
            Write-Host "Checking batch: $($batch.batchname)"
        } 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PS-ADMIN C:\Windows\system32> test
Server: server1
Checking batch: test
Checking batch: mysql
```

Comment: thanks Graimer, +1 for taking some of your time, I'm waiting to see if there are other answers

Comment: np. there may be faster ways etc. but the smartest thing is to at least separate it so your script can be called with different and multiple "rule-sets". Ex. you can make an xml for each services(mysql-cluster, web-cluster) and call them all using `"mysql-test.xml", "web-test.xml" | MyProcess` or something :-)

Comment: I, just notice than in v3 there is an automatic foreach process so you can just use $xml.servers.server to loop into each server

Comment: Yes you can use `$xml.servers.server | % { code.. }` or `$xml.servers.server.servername` etc. if that's what you meant. I'm just using xpath because I'm trying to learn it myself, and I tried to make the code as easy to understand as possible :) btw, fixed a little typo in the answer that I noticed